# How to test subscriptions/unsubscriptions in a switchmap?

Tags: system.reactive, rx-java

Note, I'm doing something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39735529/891242

```
.switchMap(flag -> flag ? processes : Observable.empty())
```

where `processes` is an `Observable<Void>`.

Is there any way to test whether the `processes` observable is subscribed to,  or if the empty one is subscribed to?

Comment: doOnSubscribe/doOnUnsubscribe

Comment: @akarnokd ah, was hoping there would somehow be a way without polluting production code with test code

Comment: state peeking operators are not just there for testing but to have side-effects along a stream.

Answer (score 1):

I exposed an RxRelay (Subject), based on the advice of @akarnokd

```
.doOnSubscribe { relay.call(true) }
.doOnUnsubscribe { relay.call(false) }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the `RxJavaHooks` class to set hooks for the events that you want, and test those calls.

Comment: You've got enough rep to know that this isn't a quality answer. You need to show how `RJavaHooks` works to solve this problem.